# An image as a button for a link will be placed after the text in a PDF and not in between

Tags: dompdf

On my site I have images in the travel report, some of which you can click on and are therefore between the a tag of a link. This works well on the site. But if a PDF is made of it, the images with links will be placed behind the text.

```
 We received the code, Robin immediately walked over to it and came back with the house key.<a href="/bonnnen.php?bon=bon0001&land=Carcassonne&eenh=€&bedr=111,40#bot"><img src="/images/pngegg64.png" alt="Receipt” title="click to view the bill" border="0" align="left"></a> After dinner to the apartment.
```

- On the website: [example HTML/PHP](https://davidbrouwer.nl/FotoserieHTML5.php?land=Carcassonne&taal=GB&foto=18&dag=D03&Hoogte=0&breedte=1920&pics=18#1) - [result in html (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO7V7.jpg)
- On PDF via dompdf: [example PDF](https://davidbrouwer.nl/DownloadPDF.php?land=Carcassonne&taal=NL) - [result in pdf (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GJvE.jpg)

Does anyone know how this can be solved so that the image also appears between the text and not after the text?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set a z-index value for your image's CSS like this:

```
img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Or try putting the

```
<a href="/bonnnen.php?bon=bon0001&land=Carcassonne&eenh=€&bedr=111,40#bot"><img src="/images/pngegg64.png" alt="Receipt” title="click to view the bill" border="0" align="left"></a>
```

in a block-level element. Wrap a `<div></div>` around it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, the <style>, <div> or <span> doesn't work. I found out that as soon as a <tag> comes after an <img...> then it goes wrong.

Comment: I found the solution: <img src="/images/pngegg64.png" align="right" onclick="location.href='/bonnnen.php?bon=ASC-2021-026&land=Wenen&eenh=€&bedr=39,10#bot'">